# error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant in c language

Tags: c, linux, cs50

Recently I've been working on a project that asks for the user's name, age, and to either confirm or deny the aforementioned information with a returned response. I've been stumped by this error message in my code, and every modification I've done only bore more errors and I'm not sure what it is that I'm doing wrong on my end. The code follows as such:

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void);
{
  //ask the user for their name
  string name = GetString();
  //prompts the user for their name
  scanf("What is your name?:%s\n", name);
  printf("Hello\n");
  }
  
 int age = GetInt();
{
   //ask user for their age
   scanf("How old are you:%i\n", age);
   printf("You are:\n");
 }
 
 //Ask user to confirm
 char confirm = GetChar();
 {
   if(confirm == 'Y' || 'y');
   printf("Thank you!");
  }
  else if(confirm == 'N' || 'n');
 {
  printf("Denied");
  }
 }
```

Compiling this code returns the following errors:

```
    project.c:13:12: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
 int age = GetInt();
           ^~~~~~~~
project.c:14:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
project.c:21:17: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
 char confirm = GetChar();
                ^~~~~~~~~
project.c:22:2: error: expected identifier or '('
 {
 ^
project.c:26:3: error: expected identifier or '('
  else if(confirm == 'N' || 'n');
  ^
project.c:27:2: error: expected identifier or '('
 {
 ^
project.c:30:2: error: extraneous closing brace ('}')
 }
 ^
7 errors generated.
```

I've tried removing the `%i` and `%s`, but that just produced more errors, I've tried removing the `;` after `int main (void);` and more errors were produced. I'm not what it is that I'm doing wrong to produce these errors, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you and cheers!

Comment: @ItsNoh Code snippets after main like this  int age = GetInt();
{
   //ask user for their age
   scanf("How old are you:%i\n", age);
   printf("You are:\n");
 } are not allowed and do not make a sense.

Comment: possible dupe of https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/24047/pset5-trie-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant

Comment: @ItsNoh You may not place statements outside a function.

Comment: @ItsNoh The semicolon in this line int main(void); makes a declaration of the function main without its definition. Start from reading a book on C for beginners. Sometimes it is useful.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I apologize for my novice understanding, likely I've jumped too deep into something I can't swim in. Would you happen to have any good recommendations?

Comment: @ItsNoh There is a list of books at this forum. You can find it here.

Comment: Note that `if(confirm == 'Y' || 'y')` does not do what you think - please compare them individually with `if(confirm == 'Y' || confirm == 'y')`. You are also using `scanf` to input what you already had from `int age = GetInt();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a whole you entire program is full of unwanted lines like `;` at the end `if` and `else`
this is not the fist time i see from people who use `cs**.h`, not sure what is wrong.

and you mixed all function definitions and calls in main function.

Refer From below program how to use function declarations, calls and definitions all are inline commented.

Refer [function syntax in c](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/c_functions.html#:%7E:text=When%20one%20piece%20of%20code,%22passed%22%20into%20the%20function.)

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// function declarations
int GetChar();
int GetInt();

int main(void)
{
    /*
    
    //ask the user for their name
    string name = GetString();
    //prompts the user for their name
    scanf("What is your name?:%s\n", name);
    */
    
    printf("Hello\n");
    
    // function call
    int age = GetInt();
    printf("You are: %d\n", age);

    //Ask user to confirm
    printf("Enter Y/y or N/n");
    char confirm = GetChar();
    
    if(confirm == 'Y' || confirm == 'y')
        printf("Thank you!");
    else if(confirm == 'N' || confirm == 'n')
        printf("Denied");
    return 0;
}

//function definitions
int GetChar()
{
    char ch;
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    return ch;
}

int GetInt()
{
    int age;
    //ask user for their age
    printf("How old are you:");
    scanf("%i", &age);
    return age;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this information! Truly appreciated, I'll give this a try.

Comment: great !! keep it up !!

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not inside a function, hence it's processed at compile time to fill the "global" section of your binary. As a consequence it **must be** possible for the compiler to compute statically the initial value of `age`.

Since you are calling a function, it's not possible hence the error you get.

Comment: Thank you for this information!